# Why declare an interface as abstract?

Tags: java, oop, interface

What's point of declaring an interface as abstract? Same thing for an interface method. Is there a point to it?

eg.

```
public abstract interface Presenter {
 public abstract void go(final HasWidgets container);
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Where did you come across the chunk of code you have posted, any old java code base ?
This is what the  [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html) has to say :

**9.1.1.1 abstract Interfaces:**
Every interface is implicitly abstract. This modifier is obsolete and should not
be used in new programs.

**9.4 Abstract Method Declarations:**
For compatibility with older versions of the Java platform, it is permitted but
discouraged, as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the abstract modifier
for methods declared in interfaces.

Comment: @Sudhir, googling for the code chunk you posted I came across this mail thread where the same issue is discussed:
http://osdir.com/ml/Google-Web-Toolkit/2010-01/msg00452.html
Also see:
http://osdir.com/ml/Google-Web-Toolkit/2010-01/msg00516.html where probable explanation for the usage is mentioned. (to paraphrase: what was started as an abstract class might have been changed to interface with the earlier modifier not being removed)

Comment: Hmmm... that would explain it.

Comment: Damn Oracle!!! The link just redirects to oracle java chronology site, pretty corporate work, doesn't even care historical evidence once you acquired it.

Comment: @sateesh Do you mean HibernateSessionFactory written is Old program ?

Comment: I saw this inside of a compiled code which was compiled by JDK 11

Answer (score 29):

Interfaces and interface methods are implicitly `abstract` even if not declared as so.  So there is no need to explicitly specify it.

Comment: All interface methods are also implicitly `public`, making declaring them as such redundant as well.

Comment: The same goes for the "public" on the method: it's implicit and isn't needed.

Comment: "public" makes it more explicit and is good for readability IMO. Abstract is pointless in this context.

Comment: @Keith: not to start a fight, but what exactly is the different between "public" and "abstract" in front of a method here? Both are implicit and can't be changed. Why should one be written and the other one not?

Comment: @Joachim: I would argue that not all developers would realize that an interface is public by default. I have always thought it to be good practice to fully qualify whether something is public/protected/private. By the definition of an interface it is abstract

Answer (score 4):

Makes no difference - interfaces and interface methods are always abstract but you don't have to add the modifier (and interface methods are always public so you don't need the public modifier too).

From the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html):

> 9.1.1.1 abstract Interfaces
>
> Every interface is implicitly abstract. This
>   modifier is obsolete and should not be
>   used in new programs.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you don't declare the interface, or its methods, as abstract. They are implicitly.

The methods are also public, so you can skip that also. :-)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380796/what-is-public-abstract-interface-in-java/4381308#4381308

interface is %100 abstract class.

the keyword **abstract** is redundant here

Answer (score 1):

"Why declare an interface as abstract?"-I got the same question and thought that abstract  is redundant. But had to rethink when I saw the Map interface in java 1.8.May be this has to be changed in java

```
//  (version 1.8 : 52.0, no super bit)
// Signature: <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;
public abstract interface java.util.Map {

  // Method descriptor #1 ()I
  public abstract int size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of an interface is essentially equivalent to what you have in your example. Defining it as abstract is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think just verboseness, explicitness and consistency with the class syntax and semantics...

You don't have to, but maybe it could help if some reader of your code is distracted or not very versed in Java.

Comment: Isn't it the opposite (as this thread proves).
If anyone is actually writing an interface they must know what an interface is. IMO this is more confusing.

Comment: If the code is not for just yourself, you should write thinking in the others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point of declaring interface to be abstract. As the methods in the interface are abstract only..
One more thing abstract class can have both concrete and abstract methods but in the interface there should be only abstract methods.

Comment: if I remember well, an interface can have concrete methods (static).

Answer (score 0):

The abstract modifier for an interface method is always redundant as well as the public modifier.

The abstract modifier on the interface itself may be redundant for a strict technical reason as an interface can never be instantiated using the new operator and the interface will always be abstract if asked via reflection.

However, there can be a semantic reason for declaring an interface abstract (that is also supported by various UML tools):
You might want to express that an interface is explicitly declared abstract in the way that a non-abstract class may not implement the interface directly but only via a sub-interface.
So e.g. you might consider the interface Node as semantically abstract while the sub-interfaces Folder and File that extend Node are semantically not abstract. You will never have an instance that is only a Node - it will be either a Folder or a File.

Even further there are frameworks that allow "instantiation" of interfaces (technically via dynamic proxies). There some interface (e.g. a predefined base interface) are not allowed to supply as argument. For documentation purpose it can make sense in the source code to use the abstract modifier to express such information.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Can we declare an Interface with “abstract” keyword?
Answer:   Yes, we can declare an interface with “abstract” keyword. But, there is no need to write like that. All interfaces in java are abstract by default. Same applies to interface methods

Please go throw this link
https://javaconceptoftheday.com/java-interview-questions-on-interfaces/

INTERFACE CAN HAVE STATIC METHOD SINCE JAVA8