# abstract interface declarations

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java abstract interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface)

Why do Java developers use `public abstract` for interfaces? Interfaces are abstract by default.

**For example:**

```
public abstract interface test{
    …
}
```

Comment: It's a matter of taste. Some developers prefer to use the abstract in every point of code where there is an abstract class (even interfaces), to make searchs easier. But it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary. According to [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1):

> 9.1.1.1. abstract Interfaces
>
> Every interface is implicitly abstract.
>
> This modifier is obsolete and should not be used in new programs.