# How can a Java interface be abstract?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I've recently realised that an interface can be declared like this in Java.

```
public abstract interface Foo
{
    // ... body
}
```

Why is this a valid syntax? Semantically, it doesn't make any sense to me (ie., an `interface` is already *abstract*, isn't it? ).
Is there any difference between an interface declared with `abstract` and the one without?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface

Comment: No difference. Every interface is implicitly abstract and this modifier is obsolete.

Comment: @Sudhanshu I agree with you that interface is implicitly abstract, though I disagree that `abstract` is an obsolete modifier. It is still in use to declare abstract classes which are clearly different from interfaces

Comment: I meant to say that using that modifier for an interface is obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

It's not required because it's implicitly there for all interfaces. There is no difference in including it or not. It's odd to include it so I would avoid it.