# Creating interface objects in java

Tags: java, object, interface

I encountered some Java code:

```
public class LocationProvider {

   public interface LocationCallback {
      public void handleNewLocation(Location location);
   }

   // class constructor
   public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback){ 
      ...
   }
}
```

For the first time in Java, I am encountering a constructor or method with an argument of a "type" that is an interface. Is it possible to create objects of interfaces ? Can you use them like regular objects ?

In C++ I know it's not possible to create objects of an abstract class.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface

Comment: You should make clearer where your class begins and ends and which level your interface has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Lets go over the basics :).

```
class A implements X{// where X is an interface
}

class B implements X{
}
```

now, we have

```
void someMethodAcceptingInterfaceX(X someInstanceOfX)
{
//do something
}
```

Now you can do,

```
X a = new A();
X b = new B();
someMethodAcceptingInterfaceX(a);
someMethodAcceptingInterfaceX(b);
```

i.e, you can pass *anything which is interface X*. Any class which implements an interface is said to be an *instance of* that interface (in a broader context).

Comment: maybe this is another question but: in C++ I know the interfaces have pure virtual methods. "virutal" - because they must be implemented by other classes, that when their objects are passes to a function as more general "interface class objects" we should know which overriding method to run. Here in java, even in the code example I gave I don't see the interface method is virtual

Comment: @Day_Dreamer - Which version of java are you using?. The answer can vary based on that :P

Comment: I don't know which Java is this code example. found it somewhere in SO. which cases exist - I'll check you already gave me enough to understand now :)

Comment: "public void handleNewLocation(Location location);" is virtual. :P

Comment: @Day_Dreamer - Ok. The *keyword* `abstract` is *redundant*. :P . Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface). and like *yellen* says, the methods of an interface are *implicitly* virtual.. You don't have to explictly mark them as *abstract* :)

Comment: @yellen - We all start at level *-1* :P

Answer (score 6):

You never create an object of "Class that is interface". You can create an object of a class that implements the interface, and pass that object as a parameter to a method that expects an argument of the interface type.

Comment: but in this code, LocationCallback  is an interface

Comment: handleNewLocation is not omplemented. ans also declared interface... what do I miss?

Comment: @StefanBeike Spiderman, Superman and Phantom all should be able to do that. But please ... don't confuse people with that kind of comment!

Comment: It means that an implemented instance of the Interface should be passed as a parameter there.

Comment: @Day_Dreamer The `LocationProvider` constructor should be passed an instance of a class that implements the `LocationCallback` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a reference's type with the referenced object's type.

#### What is going on

Instantiating a class into an **object**, and having a **reference** of a given type are two different things:

- indeed, you cannot instantiate an interface. This means:

  - you cannot call `new MyInterface()`
  - no **object** will ever have a type `MyInterface` (bear in mind that I am talking about the object here, not the reference to it).
- conversely, a **reference** can have any type that is a supertype of the type of the object it is referencing. Supertypes of a given type are:

  - all superclasses of the object's class
  - all interfaces implemented by the object's class or its superclasses

    This is called multiple inheritance of type.

Another way to see it:

- An interface cannot be instantiated
- But an interface is a valid type

In code this means :

```
MyInterface i; // This is valid, only says that the type of i is MyInterface
i = new MyInterface(); // This is not valid, cannot instantiate the interface
```

You can read about the difference between a reference type and an object's type [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730109/difference-between-object-type-and-reference-type).

#### Example

To give you an example, with the `Integer` class, which extends the `Number` class and implements the `Serializable` class :

```
Integer i = new Integer(1); // The object referenced by i is of type Integer, forever
                            // i is a reference to that object,
                            // its type is a reference to Integer
Number n = i; // Now n is also referencing the same object.
              // The type of n is a reference to a Number. 
              // The referenced object hasn't changed, its type is still Integer
              // This is possible because Number is a supertype of Integer

Serializable s = i;  // Same, s is now referencing the same object.
                     // The object is still the same, its type hasn't changed
                     // The type of s is a reference to a Serializable.
                     // This is possible because Serializable is a supertype of Integer
```

#### Application to your case

The constructor definition

```
public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback)
```

requires that the second argument be a reference to a `LocationCallback`.

This doesn't mean that the referenced object should be of that type, and indeed this is impossible. It only means that the reference passed should be a subtype of `LocationCallback`, ultimately referencing an object whose type is a class which implements `LocationCallback`.